# Freeswitch, fileaccess with javascript?

Tags: javascript, lua, freeswitch

I have a FreeSwtich solution running on Linux with quite a lot of configuration scripts written in javascript.

The problem is that we need to write and read files; which javascript normally doesn't support.
I tried the SpiderMonkey File Object but it doesn't work and has been marked as obsolete..

The setup is a bit special; there is really only one dial plan with one javascript handling the call initially. Depending on a number of parameters the call is then 'handed over' to one of 20 or so Javascripts dynamically included. It is actually a data base lookup that returns the name of the script to run.

So looking for other options if there are any? Rewriting the entire thing in LUA is an option of course but to keep the current structure that would mean rewriting a lot of javascripts. Unless someone can think of a magic way to call LUA script from javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of various programming languages supported by FreeSWITCH: Perl, Python, Lua, Ruby. Take whatever suits you better :)

Comment: why? You can keep the old scripts in JS and add new functionality in another language. If you like, we can talk tomorrow on skype:ssinyagin

Comment: Well, I'd assume it isn't possible to mix javascript and LUA in the same dialplan? There are a lot of javascript includes that would have to be converted to LUA.

Comment: depends how you use it. You did not describe your current setup, so I can't guess what's possible. Also acording to Wiki, there are file i/o methods: https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Javascript

Comment: Tried the FIle.IO and it didn't work. Explained my scenario a bit better but I think we are going to have restructure and rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

You can provide those files via an HTTP interface and fetch them from your Javascript scripts.

You can also fetch them as BLOB objects from your SQL database.

But this whole setup seems like a lot of CPU work for every call, so I wonder if performance is not already an issue.